# Show that there exists a function such that $\mu(A) = \sum_{x \in A} f(x)$ [Hint needed]

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ be an infinite set, and $R$ be the collection of all countable
>   subsets of $X$. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $R$. Show that there is a
>   function $f:X \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that
>
> $$\mu(A) = \sum_{x\in A}f(x)$$

So I've been working on this problem for a while now and I'm pretty stuck. Any candidate function I can think of violate some of the constraints. For instance, $f(x) = \text{inf} \{\mu(A_i): x \in A_i, A_i \in R  \}$ is a function from $R$, but I cannot figure out how to extend its domain to $X$ without violating the measure constraint above. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about $f(x) = \mu(\{x\})$?

Comment: Hint: What if $A$ is a singleton (i.e., $A=\{x\}$)?

Comment: $\{x\}$ is not a countable subset of $X$, so the measure is not defined for just a single $x$!

Comment: Wait, Wikipedia says that countable can mean both the finite subsets as well as the subsets isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$. Jesus, if that is the case then I have wasted so much time on this...

Comment: I've heard countable used both ways, but the only way that $R$ could be a $\sigma$-algebra is if the allowed finite sets (otherwise $\emptyset$ is not in $R$).

Comment: @TrevorNorton This particular book uses rings and sigma rings, but yes either way the empty set must be included. This would imply that finite sets are indeed allowed.

Comment: Hint:A=$\bigcup_{x \in A}\left \{ x \right \} $